# Space complexity of array of n tuples vs. 2D array of n x m integers vs. n 1D arrays of length m?

Tags: arrays, c, struct, space-complexity

I've been working on a project where I would like to store pairs of integers which got me thinking about the different ways to represent this data struct and which one would be the "best" implementation.

For example if we have a list of size n with each element containing 2 integers

```
int value1, value2
```

where we are given them in the following format

```
0 1
2 3
4 5
```

A Tuple is defined as

```
typedef struct tuple {
    int value1;
    int value2;
} Tuple;
```

We could store these values in an array of tuples, 2D array, or multiple 1D arrays which would look like the following.

Array of Tuples:

```
[(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)]
```

2D Array:

```
[
    [0, 1]
    [2, 3]
    [4, 5]
]
```

1D Array:

```
[0, 1]
[2, 3]
[4, 5]
```

Are all of these implementations equivalent in terms of space and time complexity or is there a clear "winner" out of these data structures?

Comment: @orlp It's C, I probably should have been more clear about that in my description though. The array of tuples is an array of struct pointers where there is a struct representing tuples. I will update my question.

Comment: Did you try something? For example, what are the `sizeof()` of those constructs in your environment?